# IdentityServer - AD for authentication and the rest in DB

Tags: authentication, active-directory, identity, identityserver3

I have setup a basic IdentityServer that is up and running. I'm using Identity Manager and Identity Admin to keep everything (user, roles, claims, clients, scopes) in a database. Next step is to integrate authentication with AD. My requirements are:

- User will be authenticated against AD
- User permissions (claims/roles) will be stored in database (as they are now)
- Depending on the client application, I have three different scenarios:

  - In some cases, the identity of the current user should be used (I guess for this to work, Identity Server should run with Windows Authentication). User should not be prompted for anything.
  - In some cases, the user has to explicitly login. He can use the current login or
  - Manually enter an username and password that will be validated against AD.

I'm looking for some pointers/direction how to proceed. Should I handle completely the login sequence myself, is there something similar I can base my solution, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "he can use the current login"

Comment: @stombeur Any user will be logged in Windows with an AD login and I want to use that login.

Comment: ok, I cleaned up my answer a little to make it clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around:

[This example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth)/README.md) in idsrv shows how to run windows authn in a separate web app and how to use ws-fed to delegate to that web app. This is also explained in [this issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer2/issues/358).

[This blog post by scott brady](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-WS-Federation) shows how to configure adfs to allow idsrv as a relying party and how to delegate to adfs with ws-fed to allow username/password login on adfs

If you use both these ws-fed delegations, make sure to use different values for authenticationtype.

What you could do is to force the user to try winauth first, by adding acr_values and idp to your first redirect and setting idp to the name of the winauth external idp. See [the idsrv docs here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html)

If that fails, you could use [this technique](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2489) to detect the failure to login from the external winauth provider and redirect to the adfs provider automatically.

If for some reason you do reach the login page, you can [disable local login](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html) (not show the username/password input fields) and the external providers  (winauth and adfs) will by default just show up as buttons.

---

edit:

yes, you would add an additional web app next to idsrv, that avoids having to run idsrv with windows integrated authentication

the flow for the user with winauth would be

```
client app -> IdSrv (login page) -> WinAuthHost -> IdSrv (auth endpoint)-> client app
```

actually, if successfull, the user would most likely only see the client app and one screen in the WinauthHost and never see Idsrv

If the user is not logged into windows (or not the correct domain), then the flow would be like this

```
client app -> IdSrv (login page) -> WinAuthHost ->  IdSrv login (auth endpoint, fails) 
-> ADFS ->  IdSrv login (auth endpoint) -> client app
```

Comment: I've actually used most of these except the winauth external idp and the auto-redirect on fail, but the examples seem legit

Comment: thank you. This are useful, but still I'm not clear on the overall flow. My understanding is that I will have to create another web app that runs using Windows auth and it will host IdSrv WinAuth component (let's call it WinAuthHost). For the end user the flow will be:

client app -> IdSrv login -> WinAuthHost -> ADFS -> WinAuthHost -> IdSrv -> client app.

Is that right?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what do you mean with "If that fails, you could use this technique to detect the failure to login from the external winauth provider and redirect to the adfs provider automatically."? I want user to login only using AD...if it fails the user should not login. Can you clarify please?

Comment: If that fails -> if the user is not logged into windows on his machine or not the right domain, then WinAuthHost will not issue a token back to idsrv and idsrv will consider this external authentication attempt as failed. In that case, you can detect that that attempt failed and instead of redirecting back to the client app, do another authentication attempt with another external idp, the adfs idp.

Comment: Thanx...Not yet completely clear, but it's a good starting point. Just one final question: WinAuthHost will only check the current user identity, right? If the user is not logged in domain (or in my case if for the client app the user has to explicitly login), that try will fail and the alternative will be to authenticate via ADFS?

Comment: I think so, it uses WindowsPrincipal, see https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication/blob/master/source/WindowsAuthentication/AuthenticationController.cs and https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication/blob/master/source/WindowsAuthentication/ResponseGenerator/SignInResponseGenerator.cs and it is hosted in IIS with windows integrated authn enabled https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/WebHost%20(Windows%20Auth)/WindowsAuthWebHost/Web.config, so the server challenges your account and that means the current domain or server machine.