# How can I set up local authentication combined with AD authentication using SSO for multiple micro services and a SPA application

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, identityserver4

For a customer I need to implement an authentication and authorization strategy that enables end users to authenticate to my application in two manners.

The first one is authenticating using AD, the second one is authenticating using a local account (ASP.NET identity user).

The applications I am writing are divided into multiple microservices and a front end application using SPA technology.

Now I have read about STS, but I cannot figure out how to combine AD and local login using this platform and still have STS not tightly coupled to only my applications. The purpose of this STS will be to have it be used by all of the other applications of the customer (100+).

Can anyone explain to me how to approach this in a correct manner?

Answer (score 2):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140157/identityserver-ad-for-authentication-and-the-rest-in-db) question

what you want to do is setup an instance of identityserver (idsrv) based on asp.net identity and a database (this is pretty standard)

next, you setup a separate web app that does windows integrated authN and you delegate to this one from identityserver with ws-fed. This is an external identity provider (idp) for identityserver.

the delegation to the winAuth webapp is done explicitly (user clicks a button on the login page) or implicitly (redirect to idsrv contains a preferred external idp)